# HTML submit button is not working in chrome on macOS 10.13

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, cross-browser

I'm having a problem on my Html form. I have a normal form with submit button which is

Here is the entire code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>User</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="test.php" method = "POST">
            <input type="text" name="firstname">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click on the submit button the page just moves up an inch, but does not submit the form. It works on other browser excepts on chrome.

By the way my chrome version is 85.0.4183.83 and my macOS version is 10.13
I hope you guys can help me. Thank you.

Comment: hi @LaurentC thank you for replying. Its the same page where the form is. the file location is core/controller/action_page.php. It works on other browser like safari or microsoft edge but it doesn't work on chrome. wonder why?

Comment: Thanks @MisterJojo for replying. yes there is no error in console. its kinda weird because it works on other browser except chrome.

Comment: yeah this is the first time I encountered a bug like this. When I click the submit button the pages just move up an inch and thats it doesn't submit the form.

Comment: @MisterJojo I try to do your advise changing action="/action_page.php" to action="" and putting method="post" but the submit button still doesn't work on chrome but works fine on other browser. I do have <!DOCTYPE html> on first line of my code.

Comment: did you try https://validator.w3.org/ ?

Comment: @MisterJojo I try the validator.w3.org and it throws a message "Error: Bad value for attribute action on element form: Must be non-empty." on form element. but when i revert it to this "action='/action.php'", It throws a message "Error: The character encoding was not declared. Proceeding using windows-1252."

Comment: so, you forget to have `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the html `<head>` (if your editor is utf8)

Comment: @MisterJojo I added the charset now it doesn't show any errors on validator.w3.org but still the form doesn't work on chrome browser.

Comment: for me the problem certainly comes from elsewhere on the page, and without having all of your code, it's impossible to guess. you should rewrite this whole page from scratch adding end by end to see from which segment your error appears

Comment: @MisterJojo sorry for not posting the whole code. actually it is just a simple html form thats why I'm really confused on why it is not working in the chrome browser.

Comment: @MisterJojo I edited and pasted the entire code. thank you

Answer (score 0):

i have example for you , test.php or you can post same page post function

```
    
<? if ( $opt1 == 'test' ) {
$firstname= $_POST["firstname"];
}?>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>User</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
 <form role="form" method="post" action="index.php?opt1=test" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="firstname">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```